# Guessing Game Help on JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Basically, I created a number guessing game. I have got it to work but I need help on calculating the number of guesses the user has made. This is HTML and JS Code. If the user gets the number in X amount of guesses, I want the game to display "You guessed the number in X amount of guesses!"

```js
let targetNum;

targetNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);

function checkValue() {
  let result = parseInt($(".form-control").val())


  if (result > targetNum) {

    $("#result").css("color", "red");
    $("#result").text("Too High!");
  } else if (result < targetNum) {

    $("#result").css("color", "orange");
    $("#result").text("Too Low!");
  } else if (result == targetNum) {

    $("#result").css("color", "green");
    $("#result").text("You got it!, the number was " + targetNum);
  } else {

    $("#result").text("Please re input with an actual number -_-");
  }

}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
  <!--bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <center>
    <div id=text>

      <h1>High-Low Game!</h1>
      <p>Please enter a number between 0 and 100</p>
      <div class="input-group input-group-lg" id="input">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-lg">Enter Number Here</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-lg" id="number">
      </div>
      <br>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="checkValue()">Guess</button>

      <br>
      <h2 id='result'>Make a guess!</h2>
    </div>
  </center>

  <!--javascript-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a variable in `checkValue`'s outer scope:

1. Define a variable (`guesses`) outside of `checkValue`.
2. Increment it each time the user makes a guess.
3. Change your success message to show the value.
4. Reset it to 0 after successful guess.

```js
let targetNum;

targetNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
let guesses = 0; // (1)

function checkValue() {
  let result = parseInt($('.form-control').val());

  if (result > targetNum) {
    guesses += 1; // (2)
    $('#result').css('color', 'red');
    $('#result').text('Too High!');
  } else if (result < targetNum) {
    guesses += 1; // (2)
    $('#result').css('color', 'orange');
    $('#result').text('Too Low!');
  } else if (result == targetNum) {
    guesses += 1; // (2)
    $('#result').css('color', 'green');
    $('#result').text(
      `You got it in ${guesses} guesses, the number was ${targetNum}` // (3)
    );
    guesses = 0; // (4)
  } else {
    $('#result').text('Please re input with an actual number -_-');
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   // In your JS file simply create a global variable

    let numberOfGuess=0;   //step 1

    let targetNum 
    targetNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);

    function checkValue() {

    //increment it every time you enter the function
     numberOfGuess++;     //step 2

     let result = parseInt($(".form-control").val())
     if ( result > targetNum){

       $("#result").css("color","red");
       $("#result").text("Too High!");
     } else if (result < targetNum){

       $("#result").css("color","orange");`enter code here`
       $("#result").text("Too Low!");
     } else if(result == targetNum) {
       $("#result").css("color","green");
       $("#result").text("You got it in ${numberOfGuess} guesses !, the number was "+  targetNum);  //step 3
       numberOfGuess=0; //make it zero after successful match   step 4
       return ;    // return from function if result value matches target value 
     }
     else {

       $("#result").text("Please re input with an actual number -_-");
     }

    }
```